# C# Performance counter console application running in the background on server

Tags: c#, server, background, performancecounter

I have an issue with my console application, that I can not solve or find a solution for it anywhere on the web.

Basically I have this application, that checks for CPU Performance and the Available RAM of the computer that runs the application. I'm using Performance Counters to do so.

This application works fine when I run it on my computer in the foreground, and also when I run it on the server in the foreground.

My issue is, when I run it within a Windows Service in the background, it starts but immediately crashes and I get the following errors:

- Exception in PerformanceCounter: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
- Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can anyone help or give me suggestions on how I could solve this issue.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What user are you running the windows service as? Make sure it is the same as the foreground user. It is likely that the windows service user doesn't have the required privileges to access performance counters.

Comment: This is why you should develop Windows Services as a Windows Service from day one